# Chemistry LaTeX - help

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I have recently started using LaTeX, to do my chemistry homework and I wish to display this but I have no idea on how to, is anyone able to help me[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `chemfig` package is done for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [chemfig package](https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf):

`-` draws bonds, `=` draws double bonds,`<` draws cram bonds. You will find more bonds at page 7 of the document. Number in the square brackets gives the angle of the bond. With these brackets you can give your bond optional arguments and adjust different aspects of the bond like lenght, angle, depatureof atoms.For more information see the manual on page 9.

With `\chemname{}{<name>}` you can add a name to your molecule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6((-HO)-=-(--[::-60]-[::60,,,,]NH_2)=-(-HO)=)}}{dopamine}
    
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6((-HO)-=-(-(<[::60]OH)-[::-60]-[::60,,,,]\chemabove{N}{H}-[::-60]CH_3)=-(-HO)=)}}{adrenaline}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example syntax of how to draw an aromatic ring

```
    \chemfig{**6(------)}
    
    \chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}
```

[image]

How angles work:

This is how we would simply draw butane:

```
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3---CH_3}}{butane}
```

By adding different angles of the bonds between the CH2 molecules we can complete the shape of the skeletal diagram.

```
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]CH_3}}{butane}
```

[image]